# Custom Queue Class Iteration and Data Retrieval C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indexer

So I'm working in Visual Studio 2015 with a few custom classes. One of which is called MinPriorityQueue, and it is a priority queue that, in this situation, allows me to retrieve the object of MinimumPriority in the queue via a property MinimumPriority. There is also a method called RemoveMinimumPriority, which is self-explanatory.

I am not allowed to modify this method, it was pre-made for us for this assignment, otherwise I would have already found a simple solution.

My program is meant to compare two text files, and return a value based off a certain equation which isn't important as far as this post goes. The problem I am having is within my UserInterface code. Here is my click event for the 'Analyze' button on my GUI.

```
private void uxAnalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, StoreWord> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, StoreWord>();
        const int _numFiles = 2;
        MinPriorityQueue<float, StoreInfo> minQueue = new MinPriorityQueue<float, StoreInfo>();
        int numWords1 = 0;
        int numWords2 = 0;

        //Process Both Input Files
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(uxTextBox1.Text))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _numFiles; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dictionary = ReadFile(dictionary, uxTextBox1.Text, i, out numWords1);
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    dictionary = ReadFile(dictionary, uxTextBox2.Text, i, out numWords2);
                }
            }
        }

        int[] numWords = new int[2];
        numWords[0] = numWords1;
        numWords[1] = numWords2;


        //Get 50 Words with Highest Combined Frequencies
        foreach(var entry in dictionary.Values)
        {
            StoreInfo freq = new StoreInfo(entry, numWords);
            minQueue.Add(freq, Convert.ToSingle(entry[0] + entry[1]));
            if(minQueue.Count > 50)
            {
                minQueue.RemoveMinimumPriority();
            }
        }

        //Compute and Display the Difference Measure
        float diffMeasure = 0;
        float temp = 0;
        foreach( x in minQueue)

        for (int i = 0; i < minQueue.Count; i++)
        {
            temp += minQueue.????; //This is where my problem stems
        }

        diffMeasure = (float)(100 * Math.Sqrt(temp));
    }
```

A few lines from the end you will see a comment showing where my problem is located. The MinPriorityQueue (minQueue) has two parameters, a Priority, and a Value, where the Priority is a Float, and the Value is another class called StoreInfo. This class has an Indexer, which will return information from a different file depending on what the index is. In this case, there are only two files. For example: StoreInfo[i] returns the frequency of a word in the ith text file.

Ideally, my code would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < minQueue.Count; i++)
{
    temp += (minQueue.minimumValue[0] - minQueue.minimumValue[1])*(minQueue.minimumValue[0] - minQueue.minimumValue[1]);
}
diffMeasure = (float)(100 * Math.Sqrt(temp));
```

Problem is, that would require a minimumValue property, which I don't have access to. All I have is minimumPriority.

As far as I can see, there is no other way for me to get the Values that I need in order to get the frequencies that I need to get from the indexer and put into the equation.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: since minQueue is an array or List you must get the current instance this way:  temp += (minQueue[i].minimumValue[0] - ... But if you use foreach then foreach(x in minQueue){ temp += (x.minimumValue[0] -...;}. By the way the line "foreach( x in minQueue)" must be deleted, that code should not compile.

Comment: minQueue isn't an array or a list, it is a queue. Data can only be pulled from an item at the front of the queue (aka the minimum element), therefore I can not index directly into the queue. In fact, it would probably make more sense for me to use a while(minQueue.Count != 0) instead of a for, because after each iteration, I will be removing the item, which is something I left out of the code in this post.

Comment: Also, ignore the foreach, that was leftover from me experimenting with solutions.

Comment: This said, my problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, I've been thinking at this for far too long, and it doesn't seem like anyone else sees another solution either.

At this point, I'm just going to go with the logical solution and add another property into the `MinPriorityQueue` class, even though it is against my professor's wishes.

Thank you all anyway.